# What percent of time my app server spends rendering html

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, java, jsp

My employer asked me this and I'm trying to figure out ways to measure this.

We have have several applications - some Java with Tomcat and some .NET under IIS.

To make things a little easier on myself I'm only going go deal with the Java side for now. Some apps use velocity and some use JSP/JSF.

I guess for Velocity I can put some code into our velocity view servlet to log start/end times. But I'm not sure where to look for JSP. Thoughts?

Does anyone know of any tools that can measure types of jobs the app server does?

TIA

Comment: The tool you are looking for is generically called a profiler http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming).  I don't kknow much about java/jsp stuff though.  There are some hits on Google for Java profilers. Perhaps you are able to evaluate and see if they do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the YourKit Java profiler. See http://www.yourkit.com

I have used this with clients at work to diagnose some performance issues with their JSP pages and it worked like a charm. YourKit does provide some J2EE specific measures but I tend to use the raw CPU profiling results as I am usually interested in what Tomcat is doing rather than what the JSP is doing.

In the interests of full-disclosure I should point out that as an ASF committer, I get a free YourKit license that i use to work on Tomcat.

Note that you'll often see much slower responses on the first access of the JSP while it is translated to source code for a Servlet and compiled. Subsequent accesses are usually faster.

Comment: Right. What I'd like to know is how long that part takes, and subsequent JSP processes.